Handling 0-day progression in Kaplan-Meier survival analysis
I am considering a survival analysis that examines the time spent between different levels of chronic disease multimorbidity (ML), such as ML1-ML2, ML2-ML3, etc., where MLi represents the presence of 'i' different diseases in the patient. I am planning to use Kaplan-Meier (KM) curves for this purpose. An event is either progression to a higher level or death.
There are patients I am unsure how to handle. For example, one patient is diagnosed with their first two conditions simultaneously, and a third condition is diagnosed 100 days later. This could be interpreted in two ways

as 0 days between ML1 and ML2, and 100 days between ML2 and
ML3,
or alternatively, that the patient starts directly at ML2, with no ML1 phase, and 100 days pass between ML2 and ML3.

My question is: from a survival analysis perspective, which approach is correct? In cases like this (where a level lasts 0 days), should the patient be included only in the ML2-ML3 analysis, or in both the ML1-ML2 and ML2-ML3 analyses?
